# FFmpeg: Add cover art to MP4

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4

I want to merge an audio and video file and add a cover to it.

I have the following files:

audio.mp4

video.mp4

cover.jpg

I've found the following example in the ffmpeg documentation:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -i IMAGE -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -c:v:1 png -disposition:v:1 attached_pic out.mp4
```

But I'm not sure how to modify it for my three inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp4 -i cover.jpg -map 0 -map 1 -map 2 -c copy -c:v:1 mjpeg -disposition:2 attached_pic out.mp4
```

Explanation :
-map 0 for video.mp4
-map 1 for audio.mp4
-map 2 for cover.jpg
-c:v:1 mjpeg is the codec for the second out video stream
-disposition:2 for the third out stream